# How to abort a pig script based on some value?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Is there anything in the Apache Pig to abort it from running based on value?

e.g.

y = foreach x generate 
                column1 is null ? **abortScript** : column1 as column1;

Answer (score 0):

Aborting is not possible

Possible way : Generate the data and increment some counter.

Have a next action which will check this counter and mark the result with _SUCCESS or delete the dir .